# I am getting Null value on my props on initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is I am having this output when I run/refresh my system

**{user: Array(0)}**

I use props to send my user info on my other components

Here is my **App.js** code

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([])
  const token = localStorage.getItem('mytoken')

  let navigate = useNavigate()
  
  useEffect(() => {
        ...
        .then(result => setUser(result))
      },[token])

    return (
    <div>
      <Header user = {user}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route>
        <Route path='/homepage' element = {<UserHomePage user = {user}/>} ></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      
      
      
    </div>
  );
```

And here is my other **UserHomePage.js**

```
function UserHomePage(props) {
  console.log(props)
return (
    <div>
      

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it will be null since user value getting set after a asynchronous call

Comment: Is it possible to set the User value before rendering? @SachilaRanawaka

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state to an array, but you are sending an object to the component.

```js
setUser(result)
```

should be

```js
setUser(result.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put const `token = localStorage.getItem('mytoken')` inside of the useEffect and remove the [token]

Because the token variable is not a state, it is a static variable, `useEffect` trigger point runs on state change, your token variable is not a state. A quick fix to this is empty the square brackets